# Encrypt JAVA SpringFramework WebApplication

Tags: java, spring-mvc, encryption, obfuscation, software-protection

I've created a SpringFramework WebApplication and now I want to distribute it. 
A client asked me to evaluate the applications on his own server. 
I want to protect my code encrypting the source. 
Is it possible? If yes, what's the best tool? Are there performance loss using it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use *ProGuard* in *ant task* for our release, which makes classes harder to reverse-engineer. Also it seems better for performance.

Notice that all variables which are based on injection annotations should be declared as `private`, otherwise they won't be injected correctly after the process of *ProGuard*.

[1. ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/)

[2. Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/)

Comment: Thanks! Do you have an example of configuration?